# My RelativeLayout apparently ignores my pos_hint

Tags: python, kivy, android-relativelayout

I've been trying to make a GUI for my app, and I've learned a little about RelativeLayout.
From my understanding, you define a variable "pos_hint", and assign a value from 0 to 1 which represents how close it is to that position. eg. "right": 1 == 100 percent to the right

The problem is, I have a vertical BoxLayout, containing 2 RelativeLayouts, which contain widgets, one of which also has its own RelativeLayout.
This got complicated really fast, and I am struggling to find the problem to the answer.

My objective is:
**"SuspectGraph" in the top middle, which contains 2 Ellipses overlapping eachother."**
**"SettingButton" on top right.**
**"MoodButton" at y-middle, and 1/4th of x of the bottom box**
**"FoodButton" at y-middle, and 3/4th of x of the bottom box**

From complete answers to slight hints on how to fix the bug, any help is appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to add code. Sorry.

```
<MainLayout>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0
            size: self.width,self.height
    BoxLayout:
        size: self.parent.size
        orientation: "vertical"
        RelativeLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.width,self.height
            size: self.parent.size
            SettingButton:
                size: 50,100
                pos_hint: {'right':1,'y':1}
                Button:
                    text: "Settings"
                    size: self.size
            SuspectGraph:
                pos_hint: {'center_x':1,'center_y':1}
                RelativeLayout:
                    GraphInnerCircle:
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':1,'center_y':1}
                        size: 200,200
                        canvas:
                            Color:
                                rgba: .5,.5,.5,1
                            Ellipse:
                                size: self.size
                    GraphOuterCircle:
                        pos_hint: {'center_x':1,'center_y':1}
                        size: 300,300
                        canvas:
                            Color:
                                rgba: .3,.3,.3,1
                            Ellipse:
                                size: self.size
        RelativeLayout:
            MoodButton:
                size: 50,100
                pos_hint:{'left':.1,'center_y':.7}
                Button:
                    text: "Register Mood"
            FoodButton:
                size: 50,100
                pos_hint:{'right':.1,'center_y':.7}
                Button:
                    text: "Register Food"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on how the properties work on nested widgets.
Take this snippet for example:

```
        size: self.parent.size
        orientation: "vertical"
        RelativeLayout: 
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.width,self.height
            size: self.parent.size
            SettingButton:
                size: 50,100
                pos_hint: {'right':1,'y':1}
                Button:
                    text: "Settings"
                    size: self.size
```

The pos_hint at line 12 applies to the widget "SettingButton" but not to the
button inside.
I have no idea why, but thats how it works.

Attempting to set pos_hint directly to Button does not work because it will try to infer its position from SettingButton, which is not the layout.

**SOLUTION**
Change python side code for SettingButton be a Button and not a Widget.
Apply pos_hint directly to SettingButton.

Hope this helps anybody googling the same problem!